# SQL timeout - DB not indexed

Tags: sql, timeout, inner-join

I'am currently having a slow performance problem with a SQL inner join on two tables with 10 000 000 rows. (about 10-15 minutes response)

The DB is not indexed.

Is indexing the only solution available for me?

Comment: Big Deal? Base Data? Boundary Drawing? Best Deal? Please, clarify!

Comment: @Sres: it likely stands for Base de Donnees, aka French for Database.

Comment: I am so sorry, I don't know French :-(

Comment: @UltraCommit: nobody's perfect. ;-) :D

Comment: I am the imperfection in person ;-)

Comment: You should learn about SQL indexing: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the options available to you

1. Change your query to not have a join. This is easy if the data you want is only one one table.
2. Add an index to the correct table.
3. Change your schema to not require a join. This might require moving data around, hierarchical data, or a materialized view, or some other de normalization process.

Answer (score 3):

If you're querying on a field that is not indexed, then it's going to do a table scan over the entire table (10 million rows.)

If you're doing a `like = '%blah%'` that's going to be slow as well.

It might help if you actually posted your query (or one similar) so that we could give you more info.

Comment: This is right, we need to see the queries in order to give a significative response.  1UP